# Chunking a text into 5-line chunks then working over each

Tags: python, loops, chunking

I'm trying to write a program that will take a text file organised in 5 line blocks and slice the entire text into these blocks to work on separately.

At the moment I'm trying to use:

```
text = open(filename).readlines()
chunk5 = zip(*(iter(text),) * 5)

for lines in chunk5:
    line = re.split('\n', text) # split a chunk into lines by line break
    # ...more statements
```

Please excuse me because I'm a complete beginner but is that the right way to go? I feel as though something is missing from chunk5 in the line for lines in chunk5 that would specify which chunk I'm working with.

How would I also have the program go over each chunk until it had finished with all chunks in the text too?

Comment: Why group it into chunks and then split it into lines again?

Comment: Ah the reason it's being split into lies again is because ultimately in each chunk of 5 lines I'm creating a list out line 1 and 2 each where each word in those lines corresponds to each other. After that I zip them into a dictionary of matching keys and values to add to a larger dictionary for the entire text.

Comment: @user: In that case, you don't want to split `text`. Maybe you want to split `lines[0]` and `lines[1]` or something.

Answer (score 0):

I always love generators for problems like this:

```
def chunkN(lines, N):
    acc = []
    for line in lines:
        acc.append(line)
        if len(acc) == N:
             yield acc
             acc = []
    if len(acc): # remainder
        yield acc

# Now you can do this...
for chunk in chunkN(open('myfile', 'r'), 5):
    print '-' * 80
    print ''.join(chunk)
```

I'll leave parametization of chunk size and accessing the remainder

Comment: Also check the `grouper` function from [here](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes). It's shorter and doesn't use temporary lists.